# how to access existing data in API in flutter

Tags: flutter, api

permission is asking what if I want to display the AGAMA list when making an API call. Thank You.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This all got different yesterday, thanks to patterns and destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
final List<dynamic> agamaList = jsonResponse['data']['agama'];
```

try this it should work according to me, but make sure response.body is getting printed

Comment: where is the part where i added it?

Comment: okay add this in if response.statuscode ==200 block, in that block first write the 2 lines i added and then return UserBiodata....